# Parse Push Notifications Using REST API

Tags: android, rest, parse-platform, push-notification

I have searched all over the internet but didn't get what I wanted. I want to send GCM notifications to my android app using parse rest api. I know that there is a clean documentation on Parse.com but i am confused about that what changes are needed in my application to receive those GCM pushes. I am able to send pushes, they are showing in the GCM history on developer page in google but i am unable to receive them on my phone which is irritating because there is no tutorial on what changes to be made in my application. Please if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is add the push receiver into the AndroidManifest, and this is documented.

You have to make sure the bundle id matches your app's and also there may be a GCM identifier you need to change

Comment: Thanks for teh response. I have added Push receiver in AndroidManifest and none of GCM and parse push is working. What if i only want to use Parse Pushes and no GCM.